# Signing Out User and Signing In New User

Tags: ios, swift, basic-authentication, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for basic authentication and I have a class to store to signed in users info.

My problem is when I sign a user in then sign them out and try to sign in a different user, I still get the first, signed out, users info.

**My User class:**

```
class User {
    var userJSON: [String:AnyObject]?
}

let sharedUser = User()
```

**Authentication:**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/User").authenticate(user: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!).responseJSON {
                json in
                let responseJSON = json.result.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                // print("JSON: \(responseJSON)")
                if responseJSON!["message"] != nil {
                    let errorMessage = responseJSON!["message"] as! String
                    alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    alert?.addAction(okButton)
                    alert!.view.tintColor = BarItems.greenTintColor
                    self.presentViewController(alert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    if responseJSON != nil {
                        sharedUser.userJSON = responseJSON
                    }

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("tabSegue", sender: nil)
                }
            }
```

**Sign out:**

```
     sharedUser.userJSON = nil

    // Return user to sign in screen
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

**I have also tried this suggestion [How to make basic auth with Alamofire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446325/how-to-make-basic-auth-with-alamofire), it throws "Unexpectedly found nil at `if self.responseJSON!["message"] != nil`**

```
let user = emailTextField.text
            let password = passwordTextField.text
            let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
            let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/User", headers: headers)
                .responseJSON {
                    json in
                    self.responseJSON = json.result.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    print("JSON: \(self.responseJSON)")
                    if self.responseJSON!["message"] != nil {
                        let errorMessage = self.responseJSON!["message"] as! String
                        alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        alert?.addAction(okButton)
                        alert!.view.tintColor = BarItems.greenTintColor
                        self.presentViewController(alert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        if self.responseJSON != nil {
                            sharedUser.userJSON = self.responseJSON
                            print(sharedUser.userJSON)
                        }

                        self.defaults.setObject(self.emailTextField.text!, forKey: "emailAddress")
                        self.defaults.setObject(self.passwordTextField.text!, forKey: "password")

                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("tabSegue", sender: nil)
                    }
            }
```

Comment: you should add debugging logs, maybe you are not passing new email and pass. maybe the shared User object made are being diff in each class

Comment: I just added print(sharedUser.userJSON) to viewWillAppear in my sign in controller and when authentication succeeds. It is nil before sign in and after sign out.

Comment: // print("JSON: \(responseJSON)") you have it uncommented. if you uncomment .. does it show different user details for different sign ins ?

Comment: No. It shows the same user details.

Comment: can you come to the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Comment: @Shubhank I tried the suggestion at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446325/how-to-make-basic-auth-with-alamofire

It doesn't work. I get unexpectedly found nil at my line:
if self.responseJSON!["message"] != nil